# Mostrar datos de una clase LinkedList Java

Tags: java, lista, scanner

Buenas, tengo un problema a la hora de recoger los datos de una clase, y mostrarlos en una lista enlazada.
Cuando se ejecuta el método mostrarMiLista(LinkedList list), me devuelve una salida con el formato Personas@28d93b30
Gracias.

Biografias.java

> ```
> package Ejercicio5;
>
> import java.util.Iterator;
> import java.util.LinkedList;
> import java.util.Scanner;
>
> /**
>  *
>  * @author nando
>  */
> public class Biografias { 
>
>     public static Personas cargarContactoNuevo(LinkedList list){
>
>          Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
>
>          System.out.println("Introduzca nombre y apellidos:");
>          String nombre = entrada.nextLine();
>          System.out.println("Introduzca el año de nacimiento:");
>          int añoNac = entrada.nextInt();
>          System.out.println("Introduzca el año de defunción:");
>          int añoDef = entrada.nextInt();
>          System.out.println("Introduzca área de trabajo:");
>          String areaTrabajo = entrada.next();
>          Personas nuevo = new Personas(nombre,añoNac,añoDef,areaTrabajo);
>          list.add(nuevo);
>
>          return nuevo;
>      }
>
>     public static void mostrarMiLista(LinkedList list){
>
>         if(list.isEmpty()){
>             System.out.println("La lista está vacia");
>             return;
>         }
>
>         Iterator it = list.iterator();
>
>          System.out.println("Los elementos de la lista son:");
>          while(it.hasNext())
>          {
>            System.out.println(it.next().toString());
>          }
> }
>       /**
>  * Devuelve el contenido de la lista en un String
>  * @return contenido de la lista
>  */
> @Override
> public String toString(){
>
>     String contenido="";
>     Personas aux = null;
>
>     while(aux!=null){
>         contenido+=aux.getNombre()+ "\n" + aux.getAñoNac()+ "\n" + aux.getAñoDef()+ "\n" + aux.getAreaTrabajo(); //guardamos el dato
>
>     }
>
>     return contenido;
> }
>
>     public static void main(String[] args){
>     LinkedList miLista = new LinkedList();
>     Biografias bio = new Biografias();
>     Scanner entrada = new Scanner (System.in);    
>     int opcion;
>     do{
>             do{
>             System.out.println("Elegir opción");
>             System.out.println("1. Crear ficha de contacto");
>             System.out.println("2. Mostrar contactos");
>             System.out.println("3. Salir");
>             opcion = entrada.nextInt();
>         }while (opcion < 1 || opcion >3);
>
>             switch(opcion){
>                 case 1:
>                     System.out.println("Introducir datos");
>                     cargarContactoNuevo(miLista);
>                     break;
>
>                 case 2:
>                     mostrarMiLista(miLista);
>                     break;
>
>                 case 3:
>                     System.out.println("Fin de la aplicación");
>             }
>
>         }while(opcion!=3); 
>     }
> }
> ```

Clase Personas.java

```
package Ejercicio5;

/**
 *
 * @author nando
 */
public class Personas {

    private String nombre;
    private int añoNac;
    private int añoDef;
    private String areaTrabajo;  

    Personas(String nombre, int añoNac, int añoDef, String areaTrabajo){
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.añoNac = añoNac;
        this.añoDef = añoDef;
        this.areaTrabajo = areaTrabajo;
    }

    /**
     * @return the nombre
     */
    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    /**
     * @param nombre the nombre to set
     */
    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    /**
     * @return the areaTrabajo
     */
    public String getAreaTrabajo() {
        return areaTrabajo;
    }

    /**
     * @param areaTrabajo the areaTrabajo to set
     */
    public void setAreaTrabajo(String areaTrabajo) {
        this.areaTrabajo = areaTrabajo;
    }

    /**
     * @return the añoNac
     */
    public int getAñoNac() {
        return añoNac;
    }

    /**
     * @param añoNac the añoNac to set
     */
    public void setAñoNac(int añoNac) {
        this.añoNac = añoNac;
    }

    /**
     * @return the añoDef
     */
    public int getAñoDef() {
        return añoDef;
    }

    /**
     * @param añoDef the añoDef to set
     */
    public void setAñoDef(int añoDef) {
        this.añoDef = añoDef;
    }

}
```

Comment: Disculpa la demora. Estuve sin electricidad un momento. Ya está actualizada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando pasas de leer un número a leer una cadena, antes de leerla debes de liberar el caracter `\n` que queda en el buffer al ingresar y presionar `enter`. Para que lo entiendas mejor:

1. `nextInt()`: 1234. Qeuda en el buffer `\n
2. `nextFloat()`: 9845.4. No consume el `\n` porque lee flotantes. Queda en el buffer `\n`
3. `nextLine()`: **se consume el caracter `\n`**
4. Salta la lectura de la cadena porque ya leyó.

La solución es hacer:

```
scanner.nextInt();
scanner.next(); // se consume el \n
scanner.nextLine();
```

#### Actualización

Ya que has actualizado tu pregunta para añadir una duda más, anexo esta parte.

**Reader**

```
public class Reader {

    private static final Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static Scanner get() {
        return reader;
    }

    public static void close() {
        reader.close();
    }
}
```

**Menu**

```
public class Menu {

    public static byte show() {
        byte opcion = 0;
        try  {
            Scanner entrada = Reader.get();
            do {
                System.out.println("[+] Elegir opción\n");
                System.out.println("1. Crear ficha de contacto");
                System.out.println("2. Mostrar contactos");
                System.out.println("3. Salir\n");
                opcion = entrada.nextByte();
                entrada.nextLine(); // consume el \n
                if(opcion < 1 || opcion > 3) {
                    System.out.println("Opción inválida");
                }
            } while (opcion < 1 || opcion > 3);
        } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("Opción inválida");
            Menu.show();
        }
        return opcion;
    }
}
```

**Persona**

```
public class Persona {

    private String nombre;
    private int añoNac;
    private int añoDef;
    private String areaTrabajo;

    public Persona() {

    }

    public Persona(String nombre, int añoNac, int añoDef, String areaTrabajo) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.añoNac = añoNac;
        this.añoDef = añoDef;
        this.areaTrabajo = areaTrabajo;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getAreaTrabajo() {
        return areaTrabajo;
    }

    public void setAreaTrabajo(String areaTrabajo) {
        this.areaTrabajo = areaTrabajo;
    }

    public int getAñoNac() {
        return añoNac;
    }

    public void setAñoNac(int añoNac) {
        this.añoNac = añoNac;
    }

    public int getAñoDef() {
        return añoDef;
    }

    public void setAñoDef(int añoDef) {
        this.añoDef = añoDef;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Nombre:\t%s\nAño de nacimiento:\t%d\n"+
                        "Año de defunción:\t%d\nÁrea de trabajo:\t%s",
                        this.nombre, this.añoNac, this.añoDef, this.areaTrabajo);
    }
}
```

**Biografia**

```
public class Biografia {

    private final List<Persona> contactos = new LinkedList<>();

    public void crearContacto() {

        try {
            Scanner entrada = Reader.get();
            Persona contacto = new Persona();

            System.out.print("\nIntroduzca nombre y apellidos: ");
            contacto.setNombre(entrada.nextLine());
            System.out.print("\nIntroduzca el año de nacimiento: ");
            contacto.setAñoNac(entrada.nextInt());
            System.out.print("\nIntroduzca el año de defunción: ");
            contacto.setAñoDef(entrada.nextInt());
            System.out.print("\nIntroduzca área de trabajo: ");
            entrada.nextLine(); // consume el \n
            contacto.setAreaTrabajo(entrada.nextLine());

            contactos.add(contacto);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

   public void listarContactos(){
       if(contactos.isEmpty()){
           System.out.println("La lista está vacia");
           return;
       }
       contactos.forEach(System.out::println);
   }
}
```

**Main**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Biografia biografia = new Biografia();
        short opcion = Menu.show();

        do {
            switch(opcion) {
                case 1: biografia.crearContacto(); break;
                case 2: biografia.listarContactos(); break;
                case 3: Reader.close(); System.exit(0);
            }
            System.out.println();
            opcion = Menu.show();
        } while (opcion != 3);
    }

}
```

**Conclusiones**

1. El código es el mismo pero orientado a objetos. La lectura la encapsulamos en la clase `Reader` ya que leeremos desde 2 clases: `Main` y `Biografia`. Si cerramos el `Stream` de lectura, **ya no podremos** leer aunque volvamos a instanciar `Scanner` (obtendremos un `NoSuchElementException`).
2. No es necesario devolver el contacto creado porque no se usa en ninguna parte.
3. Las clases `List` y `LinkedList` así como todas las de la familia, son **genéricas**; esto es, que permiten decidir **qué tipo de dato almacenar**, en este caso, objetos `Persona`. ¿Qué pasa si ingresamos un String? Obtendremos un error al compilar (ni siquiera ejecuta).
4. Aprovecha las nuevas características de Java 8 (Lambdas, Streams, etc.). La lectura de una lista ahora se puede hacer en una sola línea sin necesidad de `Iterator`.
5. No uses caracteres especiales/no ingleses en tus variables o de lo contrario, tendrás problemas de **encoding**.

Comment: Gracias Mitsu Gami, ahora ya salta al siguiente dato sin problema, (gracias por explicármelo), pero me encuentro que a la hora de mostrar el resultado aparece en este formato Ejercicio5.Personas@28d93b30, es porque tengo que usar los métodos get y set también, no funciona con it.next() solo?? Estoy empezando con las estructuras dinámicas y estoy un poco verde. Te agradezco la ayuda.

Comment: Ese formato se usa para representar un objeto. El método `Object#toString` por defecto retorna lo siguiente: Nombre simple de la clase, el símbolo `@` y el `hashcode` del objeto en **hexadecimal**. Para evitar y esto basta con sobreescribir el método `Object#toString` (mediante `@Override`) y hacer que devuelva lo que gustes).

Comment: estoy intentando hacer lo que me dices, y al crear el método public Personas toString(), me devuleve un error que me pone que no son compatibles los tipos y que no `puede ser reescrito. Debo estar haciendo algo mal.

Comment: Sí. En Java toda clase hereda de `Object`. El método `toString` pertenece a esta clase. Si miras la clase `Object` verás que el método `toString` devuelve un String.

Comment: Es el metodo que he creado, pero el mostrarMiLista() sigue sin funcionar. Gracias
(arroba)Override
    public String toString(){
        
        String contenido="";
        Personas aux = new Personas();
        
        while(aux!=null){
            contenido+=aux.getNombre()+ "\n" + aux.getAñoNac()+ "\n" + aux.getAñoDef()+ "\n" + aux.getAreaTrabajo(); //guardamos el dato
            
        }
        
        return contenido;
    }

Comment: Actualiza tu pregunta, pon el código nuevo y la salida que muestra.

Comment: hecho, he actualizado título, pregunta y códigos. Merci

Comment: Perfecto @Mitsu Gami, sólo he cambiado la salida para utilizar el iterator, ya que la manera en que lo pusiste tú requiere una versión más. Lo he solventado con Iterator it = contactos.iterator();
        
         System.out.println("Los elementos de la lista son:");
         while(it.hasNext())
         {
           System.out.println(it.next());
         }

Gracias de nuevo, ya me funciona perfectamente y además he avanzado más en cuanto a comprensión de POO. Saludos.

Comment: Así es, supongo estás utilizando Java 7 ;)